# How can I use sessionStorage on localhost

Tags: javascript, sessionstorage

I'm trying to use the google api to get gmail data and I'm following this tutorial:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js

However, it fails with the following error:

```
{
    "error": "idpiframe_initialization_failed",
    "details": "sessionStorage is not available in the current environment"
}
```

Any idea why sessionStorage isn't available on localhost?

I see this error in Chrome (both regular and incognito) but not in Safari (regular).

Comment: are you using safari in private mode?

Comment: I'm using Chrome. @Kai thanks for the idea, though; I've tested in Safari now and it DOES work. So unless I can get to the bottom of the Chrome problem, I can at least workaround it using Safari. I'm not using incognito mode in Chrome, btw, but I am running an ad-blocker, etc. so I'm guessing something else may interfere.

Comment: I guess you are blocking third party cookies and site data. `Parameters / Content Parameters / block third-party cookies and site data`.

Comment: https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/260